# Dygraph not showing all dates on x axis until I adjust the browser size

Tags: dygraphs

I have some Dygraphs from http://dygraphs.com/ which are initially rendered as follows with the x axis dates not rendered properly.

[image]

I then resize the browser by making it smaller and then bigger again and the graph then renders properly as follows

[image]

Code as follows:

```
      new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv_"+<?php echo $key; ?>),content_<?php echo $key; ?>, {
    legend: 'always',
    showRoller: false,
    rollPeriod: 14,
    customBars: true,
    rightGap:15,
    ylabel: 'Rating',
    strokeWidth: 1.5,
    digitsAfterDecimal: 3,
    axes: {
            y: {
                valueRange: [3, 5]
            }
        }

});
```

Is this a bug?

What adjustments would I need to make to have the graph render correctly initially?

Regards
Conteh

Comment: could you show your code, please?

Comment: @LucidioVacas I've added the dygraph code. Is there any other code that is relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following resolved the problem with the graph rendering.

```
$(function() {
        new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv_"+<?php echo $key; ?>),content_<?php echo $key; ?>, {
                legend: 'always',
                showRoller: false,
                rollPeriod: 14,
                customBars: true,
                rightGap:15,
                ylabel: '',
                dateWindow: [new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()-1, date.getDate()), new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())],
                axes: {
                    y: {
                            valueRange: [3, 5]
                        }
                }
        });
});
```